# Using Babylon js to load and customise shoe part by part

Tags: javascript, 3d, babylonjs, 3d-engine

I'm planning to use Babylon engine to develop a 3D shoe customisation website. The shoe will be customisable part to part. Like, changing the shape of front from curved to pointed, changing heel shape and size, changing texture of each part etc.,

For this is it right to create a model with submeshes and interact with to change the materials?

Is it possible to change the sub mesh in runtime, curved to pointed?

or instead of sub mesh will it be feasible to load multiple separate meshes(inner sole, outer sole, heels etc., as separate model meshes) and attach them?

Please guide me through the right path.

Answer (score 0):

the best option as you want to change mesh and material would be to load separate meshes and attach them to the same parent (with mesh.parent = dummy where dummy could be an invisible box for instance)

Comment: Please, if possible, can i have an example of this or a playground link if any.. thanks.